# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time,

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-6.0

I have created ASP.NET Web App Using MVC and Asp.Net Web Api. Both projects build using .Net Core 6. When I run both projects on local, They are working fine. But When I deployed both projects on my server (IIS),  and Accessing the api from web, it is throwing below error.

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|277_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (193.117.201.74).
```

After that I host My Api on different hosting server and Web on different hosting server. when access it is still throwing the same error.

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|277_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (irfanjanan-001-site1.btempurl.com:80)
```

*Note: The Same Api is working from postman and flutter mobile app using both IP(193.117.201.74) and Domain name (irfanjanan-001-site1.btempurl.com:80)

```
public static async Task<object> CustomHttp1(string BaseUrl, string Url, string content, HttpContext httpContext, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseUrl);

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders
                      .Accept
                      .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, Url);
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(httpContext.Session.GetString("authorization")))
                    request.Headers.Add("authorization", httpContext.Session.GetString("authorization"));
                request.Content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                try
                {

                    var Res = await client.SendAsync(request);
                    if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var response = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(response);
                        httpContext.Session.SetString("authorization", obj.Token == null ? "" : obj.Token);
                        return response;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var path = env.WebRootPath + "\\MyLogs\\Error.txt";
                    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.CreateText(path))
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
                            sw.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                    return null;
                }

            }
}
```

**Above is my method for calling my Api.**

**Note :**

1. I have created new projects for both Api & Web And Deployed. But still same issue.
2. Same Hosted API Working fine when calling from local Asp.net Web project.

Please Suggest Solution.

Comment: This can be caused by using the wrong hostname, ip address, or port. Or it could be blocked by a firewall or proxy.

Comment: The same api is working in flutter app and postman client.

Comment: Then capture  both requests in Fiddler and compare them.

Comment: Could you explain little bit? I have tried my api in fiddler and it is working fine.

Comment: Run Fiddler and have it capture the requests. Then run the request that works (e.g., Postman), and run the request that doesn't work (e.g., your app). Once you have both requests captured in Fiddler, compare them and look for differences.

Comment: Every request to Api is work fine from Postman, fiddler and flutter mobile app. But when I try to call Same Api's from Asp.Net Core MVC Web project (Which is deployed on IONOS Hosting) using HttpClient, Then It throws above mention errors.  *Note. Same Api Also works fine when calling from localhost. (Running Project in Visual Studio ).

Answer (score 1):

This issue sounds like related to IIS in your PC or server. So please check below.

1. Which OS version you use? Home Standard version has some limitions.
2. Enable websocket protocol under IIS in Windows Feature

---

**Suggestions**

1. Use another pc or server to reproduce the issue, if can't it should be related os environment.
2. Check the EventViewer and find the logs in Application. Please hide the sensitive information.